# Multi-threads method to solve Sudoku

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have to use a multi-threads method to solve a really easy Sudoku. But I don't really understand threads very well.

```
int is_finished(sudoku_t *s){
    for(int i=0;i<SUDOKU_SIZE;++i){
        for(int j=0;j<SUDOKU_SIZE;++j)
        {
            if(!correct_row(s,i) || !correct_column(s,j))
                return 0;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<SUDOKU_SIZE;i+=3){
        for(int j=0;j<SUDOKU_SIZE;j+=3){
            if(!correct_box(s,i,j))
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}


void* solver(void * sudoku_raw) {
    sudoku_t * tmp = (sudoku_t *) malloc(sizeof(sudoku_t));
    do { 
        tmp = sudoku_raw;
        fill_sudoku_smart(tmp);
    }while(is_finished(tmp)==0);
    sudoku_raw = tmp;
    return (void*) sudoku_raw;
}

void sudoku_solve(sudoku_t * s, int nthread){
    pthread_t threads[nthread];
    int i;
    for (i = 0;i < nthread;i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, solver, s);
    }
    for (i = 0;i < nthread;i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    return;
}
```

`is_finished` look if each part of the sudoku (rows, column and box are correct). correct_rows/column/box work perfectly.

After that, `solver` make a loop to fill each my sudoku.

And finally, `sudoku_solve`, that's there that the threads are created, but it doesn't work, and with my level, I can't find why.
Thank you if you can help or you took a look.

Comment: you will need to copy the contents of `sudoku_raw` instead of reassigning the pointers in `tmp = sudoku_raw;` at the moment you're operating on the same `sudoku_t` in all your threads concurrently (and leak the originally allocated `tmp`), second you'll need a way to communicate between threads, who's doing what search and once you found a solution, to stop searching.

Comment: Threading is concurrency. Read about what to take care of when concurrently accessing share resources. The latter can be variables, files, .... Access to those needs to be protected. So not two or more threads are messing around with the same resource at the same time. Hint: Access needs to be MUTual EXclusive. ;-)

Comment: This is my goto pthread tutorial: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/